# How to insert value into random row instead of appending to the end in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```py
@login_required
def add_temp(request, example_id: int=None):
    Templist.objects.create(id=example_id)
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
```

With `create` method by default, it just appends to the end of table. This is not what I want.

The existing Templist database, for example

```
id value
1  37
2  8
3  43
4  32
5  338
```

I want to insert a new value 99 into random row between 1 and 5, like a stream text.

```
id value
1  37
2  8
3  43
4  99  <- new value
5  32
6  338
```

How to solve it in a simple way?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? What use case are you trying to implement?

Comment: have you tried **`Templist.objects.create(id=postiion)`** ?

Comment: @JPG AFAIK, it won't work for existing id.

Comment: So, you want to **"replace"**  the existing position?

Comment: @Shiva I want to insert a bunch of new time-based values, recoding them every time in the temp table, for later pop (fetch and delete)

Comment: @JPG It would be fine for other empty slots. However, with Templist.objects.create(id=4, value=99), it reports error IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: myapp_templist.id.

Comment: I dont think there is a *out of the box* solution for this. You have to implement your own then

Comment: it's not a good idea to change the Id field. add another field like order and do what you want into it

Comment: @mtf Thanks. Now I am using randomly pull instead of insert.